# JSP property lookup error

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

I'm getting the following error in ours logs:

> Error looking up property "foo" in
>   object type "foo.bar". Cause: null
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor363.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.invokeMethod(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1773)

I cannot for the life of me recreate it, I was wondering if anyone has any experience with this kind of problem with JSP/Java Bean. What I wanted to know was, will this prevent the user from getting the web page to show up?

I know this isn't a whole lot of information, but any advice could help.

Comment: Looks like a nullpointer exception wrapped in a reflection exception

Comment: when you know the information is not enough, supply more ;)

Answer (score 1):

Something on some page is trying to "navigate" into a bean instance (a Java object, that is), and it's trying to get to a property that isn't there on the bean in question.

```
 <span id='name'>${fn:escapeXml(someBean.user.fullName)}</span>
```

If the bean "someBean" has no "user" property, of if the user object has no "fullName" property, you get an exception like that.

Answer (score 0):

From what you're giving here, the only suggestion I have is to make sure that you have indeed a property called "foo" and to not have a period in "foo.bar". You cannot name your variables/objects using a period in the name. JSP will automatically go and look for a property called "bar" in "foo". Call it instead "`fooBar`".

Answer (score 0):

Java is calling the getter method on the bean providing the property which is in turn throwing an exception. If you can see the target exception - that is the target of InvocationTargetException you will know what is causing this to fail.